# Minesweeper SFML code issue with revealed board

Tags: c++, sfml, minesweeper

I have problem with this code. This is Minesweeper game. The game is good, but when I move the cursor outside the game window, the whole board is revealed to me. How to fix it, does anyone know? Could you help me with this problem? I think the problem may be checking the cursor location, or the way the table is filled.

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<time.h>

using namespace sf;


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    RenderWindow app(VideoMode(400, 400), "Start The Minesweeper");

    int w = 32;
    int grid[12][12];
    int sgrid[12][12]; // For showing the grid

    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.jpg");
    Sprite s(t);

    for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            sgrid[i][j] = 10;

            if (rand() % 5 == 0) grid[i][j] = 9;
            else grid[i][j] = 0;
        }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            int n = 0;
            if (grid[i][j] == 9) continue;
            if (grid[i + 1][j] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i][j + 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i - 1][j] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i][j - 1] == 9) n++;

            if (grid[i + 1][j + 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i - 1][j - 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i - 1][j + 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i + 1][j - 1] == 9) n++;

            grid[i][j] = n;
        }

    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        Vector2i pos = Mouse::getPosition(app);
        int x = pos.x / w;
        int y = pos.y / w;

        Event e;
        while (app.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                app.close();

            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                if (e.key.code == Mouse::Left) sgrid[x][y] = grid[x][y];
                else if (e.key.code == Mouse::Right) sgrid[x][y] = 11;

        }

        app.clear(Color::White);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {

                if (sgrid[x][y] == 9) sgrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];

                s.setTextureRect(IntRect(sgrid[i][j] * w, 0, w, w));
                s.setPosition(i * w, j * w);
                app.draw(s);
            }

        app.display();
        


    }


    
}
```

[image to this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht9Nf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are updating x and y grid positions whether a mouse button has pressed or not, on this line:

```
if (sgrid[x][y] == 9) sgrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
```

Also, it looks like you are checking the display `sgrid[x][y]` instead of the data `grid[x][y]` at the mouse click location.

What you'll most likely want to do is add a flag for when a mouse button is clicked and only check for a mine when the button is clicked.  I made a couple small changes in the code below, give it a try:

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<time.h>

using namespace sf;


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    RenderWindow app(VideoMode(400, 400), "Start The Minesweeper");

    int w = 32;
    int grid[12][12];
    int sgrid[12][12]; // For showing the grid

    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.jpg");
    Sprite s(t);

    for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            sgrid[i][j] = 10;

            if (rand() % 5 == 0) grid[i][j] = 9;
            else grid[i][j] = 0;
        }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            int n = 0;
            if (grid[i][j] == 9) continue;
            if (grid[i + 1][j] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i][j + 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i - 1][j] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i][j - 1] == 9) n++;

            if (grid[i + 1][j + 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i - 1][j - 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i - 1][j + 1] == 9) n++;
            if (grid[i + 1][j - 1] == 9) n++;

            grid[i][j] = n;
        }

    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        Vector2i pos = Mouse::getPosition(app);
        int x = pos.x / w;
        int y = pos.y / w;
        bool mbleft = false;

        Event e;
        while (app.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                app.close();

            if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                if (e.key.code == Mouse::Left)
                {
                    sgrid[x][y] = grid[x][y];
                    mbleft = true;
                }
                else if (e.key.code == Mouse::Right) sgrid[x][y] = 11;

        }

        app.clear(Color::White);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {

                if (mbleft && sgrid[x][y] == 9) sgrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];

                s.setTextureRect(IntRect(sgrid[i][j] * w, 0, w, w));
                s.setPosition(i * w, j * w);
                app.draw(s);
            }

        app.display();
        


    }


    
}
```